# Smooth transition from position relative to fixed

Tags: jquery, css

In my website I have a div with relative position, this div have `bottom:0` and `width: 100%` and when the user scroll on the page the div changes to fixed position, also with bottom 0 and width: 100% (the div moves from a concrete position to the bottom of the page).
I do this with jQuery, but I can't apply a smooth transition. How could I do this? I tried with .animate() but doesn't work.

This is the script

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
         let a = 350;
         let pos = $(window).scrollTop();
         if(pos > a) {
             $("#button-presupuesto").addClass('isFixed');
         }else{
             $("#button-presupuesto").removeClass('isFixed');
         }
    });
});
```

And the css:

```
.isFixed{
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can not “transition” between different positioning methods. You would have to calculate/get the elements current position in relation to the viewport when it is still “relative”, switch to fixed using those coordinates first, and then you could transition/animate them to the final fixed values you need.

Comment: Have you looked into `position: sticky`? It might do what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yes, but the element is positioned in a block that not cover all the page, so the sticky is not usefull for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should set its position to `fixed` and use `transition` with `visibility`, `opacity` to make it smooth.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
         let a = 100;
         let pos = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (pos > a) {
             $(".bottom-bar").addClass('isFixed');
         } else {
             $(".bottom-bar").removeClass('isFixed');
         }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: system-ui;
 padding-bottom: 80px; /*Spacing for bottom-bar*/
}
p {
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.bottom-bar {
 background-color: #000a;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.isFixed {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacinia ultricies sollicitudin. Sed mattis aliquet tempus. Morbi euismod bibendum turpis, ac vulputate lorem egestas et.</p> 

<p>Quisque vitae felis lorem. Nunc luctus orci eu turpis ullamcorper lobortis. Ut sed eros non nunc molestie sollicitudin id sed turpis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
<br/><br/><br/>
Maecenas aliquam urna tellus, suscipit euismod tortor faucibus at. Quisque eget imperdiet purus. Sed rhoncus semper risus, quis suscipit dolor elementum nec. Sed nunc est, molestie ut ullamcorper quis, posuere non felis. Vestibulum in fermentum sem, vitae pulvinar eros.</p>

<p>Nullam enim ligula, faucibus hendrerit nibh ac, facilisis rhoncus nulla. Fusce ac cursus velit, ut molestie purus. Suspendisse vulputate metus nec commodo semper. Vestibulum eu tincidunt ligula.</p>

<p>Cras quis consequat quam, ut faucibus arcu. Donec finibus massa ac ex rutrum dictum. Donec justo orci, faucibus quis enim eu, dictum rhoncus justo. Vivamus ornare ullamcorper dolor. Integer consequat justo pretium, vestibulum mi et, gravida tortor. Etiam vel neque vehicula, volutpat erat sit amet, dictum tellus. Donec luctus tincidunt ipsum quis facilisis. In aliquet sit amet sem eget mattis.</p>

<p>Nam maximus ac neque et pretium. In pulvinar lacus eu erat aliquet faucibus. Nulla aliquam scelerisque lectus non fermentum. Aliquam nec placerat tellus. Vestibulum volutpat elit sapien. Nullam scelerisque tortor a elit imperdiet, eget pellentesque nulla hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Nam sit amet dictum est. Praesent ultrices finibus aliquet.</p>

<p>Curabitur tortor enim, dictum varius tincidunt in, varius sit amet lectus. Duis imperdiet dignissim metus, ac placerat sem accumsan eget. Morbi vel vestibulum orci. Etiam vel diam vel lacus ultricies rutrum ut eget metus. Integer in mauris tincidunt, dignissim lectus a, hendrerit est. Nulla tincidunt malesuada diam, vel condimentum nisl varius at.</p>

<p>Sed consequat tortor a dignissim fermentum. Sed dolor augue, commodo id viverra id, dictum sit amet nunc. Vivamus nisi nisi, vehicula in pulvinar sit amet, aliquam at mi. Fusce vitae arcu ut nisi luctus congue. Morbi sit amet rutrum est. Nullam nisi nibh, vulputate ac ex ac, ultricies commodo lacus. Mauris consequat ut sem vitae pulvinar. Phasellus faucibus vestibulum accumsan.</p>


<div class="bottom-bar">
 Hello!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Phap, but my problem is quite different, the "bottom-bar" element is always visible, just change from relative position to fixed at the bottom when the scroll is more than over 300px

Comment: @PabloLeón: `position` doesn't support animation so you can not just barely change the `position`.

Comment: Allright, finally I've animated change in the `bottom` prop, as you said was imposible to animate the `position`